# infinite-dimensional transversality theorem and its application on the universal moduli space of pseudo-holomorphic curves

Tags: moduli-spaces, symplectic-topology, infinite-dimensional-manifolds, transversality, pseudo-holomorphic-curves

We would like to discuss **Proposition 3.2.1** in McDuff&Salamon's book "*J-holomorphic Curves and Symplectic Topology*(Second Endition)".

> Let me first remind you some background. Let $\Sigma$ be a compact
>   Riemann surface, $(M,\omega)$ a compact symplectic manifold and $A\in H_2(M,\mathbb Z)$. Define $\mathcal B^{k,p}=\{u\in W^{k,p}(\Sigma, M):
> [u]=A\} $ for suitable $k$ and $p$, and define $\mathcal J^l$ to be
>    the space of all $\omega$-compatible almost complex structure of class $C^l$.
>
> The proof involves a Banach space bundle $\mathcal E^{k-1,p}\to
>  \mathcal B^{k,p} \times \mathcal J^l $ whose fiber over $(u,J)$ is the
>    space $W^{k-1,p}(\Sigma, \Lambda^{0,1}\otimes_J u^*TM)$ of
>    $J$-antilinear 1 forms on $\Sigma$ with values in the bundle $u^*TM$.
>    Then a section is defined by $$ \mathcal F: \mathcal B^{k,p} \times
>  \mathcal J^l \to \mathcal E^{k-1,p},~~(u,J)\mapsto \bar\partial_J(u)$$
>
> Now, the universal moduli space
>
> $$\mathcal M^*(A,\Sigma;\mathcal J^{l}):=\{ (u,J)\in\mathcal
>  B^{k,p}\times \mathcal J^l: \bar\partial_J(u)=0,
>  [u]=A  \}$$ is just the preimage $\mathcal F^{-1}(\mathcal
>  B^{k,p}\times \mathcal J^l)$ of the zero section of $\mathcal
>  E^{k-1,p}$ (By the way, the definition of this universal moduli space
>   in this book is different from the above one which I prefer)

The **Proposition 3.2.1** states that $\mathcal M^*(A,\Sigma;\mathcal J^{l})$ is a separable $C^{l-k}$-Banach submanifold of $\mathcal B^{k,p}\times \mathcal J^l$.

**(1).** I guess the proof in this book uses an infinite-dimensional version of transversality theorem which the book mention neither in the text nor in the Appendix, rather than the implicit function theorem which the Appendix do mention. Do you know the precise statement of this infinite-dimensional transversality theorem? Thanks

**(2).** On the other hand, I feel confused about how to obtain from Proposition 3.1.1, as the book proposed, the formula of the vertical differential $$D\mathcal F(u,J)(\xi,Y)=D_u\xi+ \frac{1}{2}Y(u)\circ du\circ j_\Sigma $$ Can anyone provide further details of this formula? Thanks